# how to read data from file line by line and storing each token in a line in vectors for further use(c++)

Tags: c++

I have data in the following format  (N  Snode Sterminal Dnode Dterminal):

5

4

1   2  3  4  5

6  7  8  9  10

11 12 13 14 15

...

For the first step, I am trying to read line by line but in my output I could only output the last line but not the rest. After reading line by line, I have to store each column into vectors.

my code:`

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int cell, con, N,Snode,Sterminal,Dnode,Dterminal;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("file");
    infile >>cell;
    cout<<cell<<endl;
    infile >>con;
    cout<<con<<endl;
    while(infile>>N>>Snode>>Sterminal>>Dnode>>Dterminal);
        {
            cout<< N <<"\t"<< Snode<<"\t" << Sterminal<<"\t" << Dnode<< "\t" << Dterminal <<endl;
        }
}
```

`

my output:

5

4

3  5  6  7  8 //last line in the file

I further want Snode, Dnode, Sterminal, Dterminal as vectors so that i can save the respective columns in it.

Comment: Always check that the file actually did open. Always check that all input operations succeeded.

Comment: It did open as I could read the first two lines and the last line. But thanks, will add in the code.

Comment: "I am trying to read line by line". If so, then why are you wasting your time using `>>`? This is like trying to use a screwdriver in order to hammer in a nail. That's not what `>>` is for. If you want to read your input one line at a time, that's what `std::getline` is for. Use the right tool, and the right function, for the right job.

Comment: I edited that in my code already. But after/while reading the data I want to store each column into vectors. how do I do that? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: After reading a single line into a `std::string`, use that to construct a `std::istringstream`, then use `>>` to extract the individual columns from *that*.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik. I started c++ this week and I am learning as I code! :)

Comment: As a side note, have you considered instead of vector, using a struct {int N, Snode, Sterminal, Dnode, Dterminal} so you can refer to them by name, rather than cryptic indexes like v[3] ?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Is it similar to constructor? I have to map 2&3 column with 4&5 to establish a connection between them.

Comment: If you want vectors, push the values to the vectors where you currently do cout.